# DUAL table query

Tags: database

How do I construct the following query with DB API (so it's database engine independent):

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

This example is for MySQL. I believe the Postgres version is

```
SELECT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting dual as the alias instead of the table.

```
$query = db_select(NULL, 'dual');
$query->addExpression('1');
```